# React Native: Expo what is different standalone android app

Tags: react-native, google-play, app-store, expo

I am using expo to create a react native application. There are settings app.json which i am not sure what it mean.

Standalone Android Apps , Standalone iOS Apps settings.

Are those settings required before build the app and upload to playstore/appStore?

Comment: Value for '`bundleIdentifier`' for '`ios`' and `package` value for `Android` The remaining settings are then required if `expo eject` becomes `Standalone App`.

Comment: if the app was not ejected, how the icons and other images work for android and iOS device

Comment: You can use an icon or image without `expo eject`. `import { Image } from "react-native";` `import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";`

Comment: sorry i mean the appIcon show on device. e.g. iOS have app icons to insert it into assets folder for many different devices.

Comment: See here. it help you https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/images/